# How to Configure Servlet Mapping and Resource Handler in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mapping, http-status-code-404, static-resource

I have created sample Spring MVC REST Maven project with following folder structure
[image: Folder structure]

ResourceHandlerRegistry configuration as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.raju.spring_app")
public class RootConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static_res/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/html/static_res/");
    }
//Other methods 
}
```

Servlet mapping as follows

```
public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/", "/static_res/*" };
    }
    //Other Methods
}
```

The problem is whenever I tried to access resource 
    http://localhost:8080/spring4_rest_angular_demo/static/css/app.css

I got 404 error.
I want to keep this folder structure to get css IntelliSense suggestions 
in index.jsp file.

```
<link href="static_res/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few corrections :

Replace

`return new String[] { "/", "/static_res/*" };`

with

`return new String[] { "/" };`

and

`registry.addResourceHandler("/static_res/*")`

with

`registry.addResourceHandler("/static_res/**")`

Also, the right path is

`http://localhost:8080/spring4_rest_angular_demo/static_res/css/app.css`

and not

`http://localhost:8080/spring4_rest_angular_demo/static/css/app.css`

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 3.0.4.RELEASE and higher you can use

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

As seen in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources

Also, you should avoid putting pages in `WEB-INF`. Put the folder with `html/css/js` higher in hierarchy, under the web app folder. Generally, in `WEB-INF` there should be only configuration xml files.

Comment: 1) He is using Java config equivalent of the code you posted. 2) You should put resources outside WEB-INF but the JSPs should remain inside WEB-INF folder. This way it won't be directly accessible by the client - it should be served by a controller.